# Do I always need to know the schema of the JSON response that I am getting?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I am making a `GET` request and getting a response that is heavily nested. In Python, I'd simply use a variable to hold the JSON response, and just do `variable['key']['key']...` (or `variable.get('key').get('key')...`) - you get the point.  Can I do that in RUST? I am going over `Serde`, but I still see that I need to have a struct of the schema. Can that be avoided?

I am probably overlooking something, so any pointers on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look at [serde_json::Value](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/enum.Value.html), it allows for dynamic typed json without creating a struct of the schema.

Comment: Yes I looked into that, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize your data as serde::Value and use the [get](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/enum.Value.html#method.get)
method on it